# How to get the base address of a loaded .so in memory?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, embedded-linux

I am working on an embedded Linux program. The scenario is:
There're thousands of configuration items which are compiled statically in the final executable, and the address of the items is defined in the linker script, e.g.,

```
firstConfigItem = .;
*(.SEGM_CONFIG)
lastConfigItem = .;
```

so that the variables `firstConfigItem` and `lastConfigItem` are used directly in source code.

Now the trouble is, even there's an insignificant modification in only one config item, the executable should be re-compiled.

So my idea is, to compile all the config items as an .so file then load it dynamically.

Is that feasible? If yes, how can I initialize `firstConfigItem` and `lastConfigItem`? Is there any api in Linux that can get the loaded addr of a specified so?

Or, can anyone recommend a easier way?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi Feng, dlopen can be used to load a shared library and having done that dlinfo can be used to retrieve information (eg. address) of the shared library (at a linux terminal if you type 'man dlopen' and 'man dlinfo' it will give details on the syntax)- not sure how it fits in with your config items list though

Comment: If you wish to make it flexible, make every item an independent shared object (plugin), and startup time load every plugins from a dedicated directory (NB think of access right, you don't want to run any malware put there by others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Should work just fine:

1. open the shared object with `dlopen`
2. obtain the address of the desired symbol using `dlsym`
3. write that address into a variable for later use

What's important is that you pass the handle of the object to `dlsym` so you get the symbol from the shared object and not from some other component that might define it.

You can also produce a dummy configuration object and link against it at build time.  At runtime before starting the program, you place the correct configuration object into the rpath, allowing your program to automatically find it.  Then you don't need to do anything at runtime, it's just a link with a shared library.

Comment: 2 questions: 1, 
For the 1st solution, i need to write something like this: void * pConfig = dlopen("/path/to/my/libconfig.so", RTLD_LAZY); void* pFistItem = dlsym(pConfig, "xxxItem"); then i need to know the exact name of the first config. Did i understand it correctly?

Comment: For the 2nd solution, Do I also need to call dlopen() and dlsym()? Can you elaborate it pelase?

Comment: For the first solution, your understanding is correct.  For the second solution, you do do not need to call `dlopen` or `dlsym`, it's just like a normal link with a shared object.  You reference the symbol you need from your code and the runtime linker will figure out how to get it.

Comment: Then I keep the link script unmodified, and just compile the final executable app with -Wl,rpath=/path/to/lib/, meanwhile, put libconfig.so to /path/to/lib. All set. I can use config_item_xyz directly now. Right?   firstConfigItem and lastConfigItem are irrelevant variables now?  Currently there're some logic to traverse all the config items, e.g., validity check. So I need to set firstConfigItem and lastConfigItem by myself. Yes?

Comment: @feng Yes, correct.  You don't need the variables anymore.